# реализация паузы музыки через два прохода

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите как можно реализовать следующее: музыка проигрывается в начале игры, когда музыка пройдет два раза, сделать паузу не проигрывать ее секунд 20

Сделал корутинами, но в проекте их слишком много, какие еще способы есть

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine ("CheckMusicListener");
}
void Update()
{

    if (CheckisMusicSound == 2) {
        MusicSource.Stop ();
        StopCoroutine ("CheckMusicListener");
    StartCoroutine ("CheckIsMusicIterators");
        CheckisMusicSound = 0;
    }

}


private IEnumerator CheckMusicListener()
{

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(MusicSource.clip.length);
    CheckisMusicSound++;
    StartCoroutine ("CheckMusicListener");
    Debug.Log ("Музыка закончилась с итератором "+CheckisMusicSound);
}


private IEnumerator CheckIsMusicIterators()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
    MusicSource.Play ();
    StartCoroutine ("CheckMusicListener");

}
```

Comment: `какие еще способы есть` - события. прочитать про события

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался)